# React text input inside modal not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

i have this custom modal that render a children element

```
function MyModal({
  children,
  setShow,
}: {
  children: JSX.Element;
  setShow: (data: boolean) => void;
}) {
  return (
    <div
      className="absolute top-0 w-full h-screen flex flex-col justify-center backdrop-blur-md"
      onClick={() => setShow(false)}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyModal;
```

I wanna render different elements inside of it, so i created this state

```
 const [element, setElement] = useState<JSX.Element | null>(null);
```

I'm calling the modal as

```
{show && <MyModal children={element} setShow={setShow} />}
```

I'm setting the children as this

```
<button
          onClick={() => {
            setElement(AddNewTask);
            setShow(true);
          }}
        >
          Add
        </button>
```

And it's working ok, it opens and closes fine, but the text input of the rendered element is not working, nothing types. This is the AddNewTask component that i'm rendering

```
const AddNewTask = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div
      className="bg-green-400 p-20 rounded-md"
      onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
    >
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          addTask();
        }}
      >
        <input
          value={content}
          onChange={(e) => setContent(e.currentTarget.value)}
          placeholder="Tarefa"
        />
      </form>
      <button onClick={addTask}>Adicionar</button>
      <button onClick={() => setShow(false)}>Cancelar</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I think you probably need to change `e.currentTarget` to `e.target` in your onChange method, but I'm not sure

Comment: Still not working :/

Comment: Where are you defining `content` & `setContent`?

Comment: Turns out i was defiyning it in the parent component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setContent` method in the AddTask Component is undefined/ only defined through scope. You need to pass it as a prop to the AddTask component to work or alternatively create the state inside the component with a useState hook.

Comment: It worked, i just created the state inside the component. Thanks!